# Android Picture-in-picture mode, open another activity of my app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-picture-in-picture

I have a video call activity and I am using pip mode for it. In pip mode, I try to open related chat activity using remote action. But when a startActivity is called from pip activity, the new activity is being opened in the pip screen too. But I do want to open the chat in our app, not in pip screen.
Is it possible to start our own activity outside of the pip screen?

Comment: have you fixed this issue? as I am getting the same issue like when I start a second activity from the PIP activity.PIP view of the previous activity does not come up

Comment: Yes I fixed it with the answer below. You should add something like that to your pip activity in the manifest: `android:taskAffinity=".YourActivityNameOrAnyString"`

Comment: Ok, but my issue is a bit different as when I start a new activity from PIP Activity the PIP view doesn't come up any help in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding taskAffinity solves my problem.
You can see detail here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#aff

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for it and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding launchMode of VideoActivity as singleInstance in manifest file solves the problem.
ex.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance".
```

It will allow to enter PIP activity in separate task so it will resolve back press and next screen navigation issues automatically.